# How would one make an asynchronous function with CreateThread?

Tags: c, asynchronous, winapi

I have this simple code that create a thread which calls the function `DoStuff`, but this approach is blocking (synchronous) prevents main from doing other stuff until the thread is done or terminated, how would one convert such code such that main completes all other execution while the thread is running another function

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

DWORD WINAPI DoStuff(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    printf("Hello from thread\n");
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // Create a new thread which will start at the DoStuff function
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,    // Thread attributes
        0,       // Stack size (0 = use default)
        DoStuff, // Thread start address
        NULL,    // Parameter to pass to the thread
        0,       // Creation flags
        NULL);   // Thread id
    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        // Thread creation failed.
        // More details can be retrieved by calling GetLastError()
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait for thread to finish execution
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    printf("Hello from parent\n");

    // Thread handle must be closed when no longer needed
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove `WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);` or place other code between `CreateThread` and `WaitForSingleObject` - in what problem ?

Comment: Pass the worker thread a callback function or the address of a flag or struct for it to update once it has finished, do not wait for it at all.  Either the callback gets called or you poll the state of the struct.

Comment: In an actual program you would have a loop doing stuff while waiting, and either gets notified or polls for the asynchronous task's completion. If you really have a blocking operation and no other useful work to be doing there isn't any point in making it asynchronous.

Comment: MS recommends using [`_beginthread()`/`_beginthreadex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=msvc-170) instead in C runtime programs btw

Comment: @DaveS could you show an example of how to use the callback approach

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the sample: [Asynchronous Function Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wsw/asyncmodelexample)

Comment: `#include <Windows.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>` in the same program doesn't seem wise. You might want to decide if you are compiling for Windows or Unix, even if you are using Cygwin or something like that.

Comment: The first question you should ask is: Do I need multiple threads at all? Windows provides native support for [asynchronous I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o). If all you're doing is I/O, there's no reason to spin up an extra thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is done by swapping `WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);` for  `WaitForMultipleObjects`. The latter takes an array of "waitable" things as parameter and allows you to wait until one of several things have occurred, or until all of them have occurred.

When designing threads you'll always want threads to close down gracefully by signalling it, for example through an event, rather than to bluntly clobber it dead with some termination function.

Meaning that in fact `WaitForMultipleObjects` should pretty much always be used and almost never `WaitForSingleObject`, because you'll want to wait both for the thread handle(s) and the close down event(s), and probably for a lot of other "waitable" stuff like mutexes.

Similarly, you can call `WaitForMultipleObjects` in a `while` loop, optionally with a fixed timeout, then check what reason it occurred and act accordingly.